# How do you install Jekyll on OSX?

Tags: macos, jekyll

I was following [the instructions here](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/install), so I ran `gem install jekyll` on my osx machine, and got the following:

```
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and
      /usr/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/erikvold/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
liquid requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.7
```

But I don't see instructions on how to deal with this in the instructions above.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to update `gem` first:

```
$ gem update --system
```

In case you get permission errors, you must resort to `sudo` for this and all other gem commands:

```
$ sudo gem update --system
```