# Install Jekyll on OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, rubygems, jekyll

I am having trouble installing Jekyll on my computer and was hoping someone might be able to help me troubleshoot. I've detailed the Stack documentation I have reviewed below.

Here is the error I have been receiving:

```
sudo gem install jekyll
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150209-80771-11wqezc.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
make: *** No rule to make target `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14/ruby/config.h', needed by `porter.o'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/gem_make.out
```

First I made sure `gem` was updated ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904786/how-do-you-install-jekyll-on-osx)):

```
gem update --system
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
```

Next, I made sure that xcode was installed as per this stack answer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725767/error-installing-jekyll-native-extension-build)).

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: i can't reproduce that, `sudo gem install jekyll` produced no errors for me on yosemite.

Comment: Are you sure Ruby is installed and up to date?

Comment: Yeah, here's what I see when I check whether Ruby is installed and up to date: `ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]`

Comment: I'm stumped, and am still unable to get this to work, so if anyone has any suggestions I'm all ears.

Comment: @chris What version of ruby are you using? Is there anything else that could be causing this issue? Should I uninstall everything and reinstall it?